# Privacy issue when using Firestore as a main database

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner developer and this is my first time using Firestore.

I'm trying to create a simple schedule app for personal learning, and if possible, I'd like to release it on the app store. I'm currently using the Firestore database to store the schedule titles and detailed memos and other stuff like due dates, etc. entered by users as string values.

However, I noticed that through the Firestore console, I, as the developer, can see the content entered by users. In a way, it could be seen as a situation where sensitive information or the privacy of individual users is exposed to me as the developer. I'm concerned that this could be a reason for rejection during the app review process on the app store or Play Store. I also think that users would be very uncomfortable if they knew about this.

At least for the purpose of releasing on the app stores, I wonder if it is necessary to encrypt or secure the parts related to privacy, such as schedule names and detailed schedule memos, separately in Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want developers (or other collaborators on the project) to be able to see the data in Firestore, you can either:

- Remove their ability to see Firestore altogether through [IAM permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions).
- [End-to-end encrypt](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+end+to+end+encryption) the data, storing the keys in a place where the collaborator can't access them.